# Re-write content in the ACF WYSIWYG editor using jQuery on a button click

Tags: jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wysiwyg, chatgpt-api

I am trying to code a plugin for Wordpress to integrate an option to generate content using Chat GPT for some ACF custom fields.

I have 3 ACF WYSIWYG editors inside an ACF group and I have used the following code to append buttons to the ACF group;

```
(function() {
    jQuery('.acf-field-group').each(function() {
        var $tabGroup = jQuery(this);
$tabGroup.append('<div class="custom-btns"><button class="button" id="button1">Button 1</button><button class="button" id="button2">Button 2</button><button class="button" id="button3">Button 3</button></div>');
})();
```

This has now added the buttons to the ACF group. I am trying to replace the content with the chat GPT response I get when I click each button. I am not quite sure how I could update the content of each WYSIWIG editor once the button is clicked.

```
tinymce.init({
                selector: editorID, // Replace with the class name of your WYSIWYG editor
                init: function(editor) {
                  editor.on('init', function() {
                    sendRequest(chatgptPrompt, ed)
                 });
             }
 });
```

"sendRequest" is the function I use to handle the API request and in this function I use the following to set the content to the editor. However it messes up my WYSIWYG editor by adding in extra options

```
editor.setContent(generatedText);
```

[WYSIWYG editor after button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae4dC.png)

Appreciate any help on how to replace the content in the ACF WYSIWYG on the click of the buttons.